# concatenate import url in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, string-concatenation, tslint

I'm developing a software using typescript 2.0.3 and tslint 4.0.2 and angular. 
 I have an issue since my import url is too long for tslint standard. Changing line limit in tslint is not possible in my case. 
I tried separate the url to pieces and concatenate them, but it doesn't work.
Basically this is what I have:

```
import {  blabla } from
'./really long string (around 200 characters)';
```

and this is what I need:

```
import { blabla } from
'100 characters here' + '100 characters there';
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your "really long" import string?

Comment: './approvals/approval-personnel-admin/approval-bpjs-healthcare/approval-bpjs-healthcare-family-membership/approval-bpjs-healthcare-family-membership.component';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot split the import string.
If your path is a/b/very_long_c/blabla, You can create an index.ts inside a/b containing

```
export * from './very_long_c/blabla';
```

and use this in your code:

```
import { blabla } from 'a/b/index';
```

Comment: You can drop the `index` from the import statement. It will automatically look for `index.ts` if given a directory.